# getting multiple values from a form using ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

hi all ive found this script and ive been amending it but im not sure how to change it so it can handle multiple values.. ive got a form with many different select options and im tryin to pass all the selected options to my ajax.php page where ive got a mysql select statement that uses the selected options to perform a search result. the code below works but only on the first two selected options. can anyone help?

Cheers

```
 $(function() {


            $("#lets_search").bind('submit',function() {
                var value = $('.option:selected').val();
                $.get('ajax.php',{value:value}, function(data){
                    $("#search_results").html(data);
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pull out the other values using .val() and add them to the object

```
     var value = $('.option:selected').val();
     var value2 = $('.text').val();
     $.get('ajax.php',{value:value,value2:value2}, function(data){
          $("#search_results").html(data);
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.each or .live`